# Distribute Laravel Dusk Tests to Selenium Grid

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, laravel-dusk

I have a Laravel Project (5.4) with about 8 Dusk Test files. I also have a Selenium Grid running with 8 Chrome Nodes.

I want to send one Laravel Dusk Test file to each Chrome Node. Is there an easy way to do so? or is it even feasible? I have a way now but it is manually typing in each `@group` tag when running dusk.

i.e. I open multiple powershell windows and type `php artisan dusk --group=NAME_OF_TEST` into each and press enter.

---

Ex. `php artisan dusk --distribute`

This would then start multiple Chromedrivers in `DuskTestCase.php` and send them, at the same time, to the Selenium Grid's URL.

---

Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Found a better work around. I grab all the groups that are listed above my Testing functions and paste them into a text file. From there, I can "read" it line by line (with something like a python script) and call dusk on each line.

Example:

`php artisan dusk --list-group` will return all available "groups" (`@group blah`) that are written above any test functions. So I can do
`php artisan dusk --list-group > file.txt` and that will paste all the groups into a text file. Then I can open the text file in python and read it line by line.